# Should we use a [follow-up] tag when posting a follow-up?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am looking at creating a [follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/follow-up) tag, but thought that I should get everyone's opinion on it before I start tagging things sporadically here and there.

I think that creating this tag will benefit the more active users of the site, by helping them to help others, kind of like a teaching aid.

A lot of users don't participate in chat, but more often they post follow up reviews.

I think that a follow up tag will benefit reviewers by pointing them to updates of the code they have helped review in the past.

I don't see how this tag is much different than [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) or [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge), with this tag a user can follow the follow up posts like they would the game posts or the tic-tac-toe posts ([tic-tac-toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe))

---

Searching for "[`follow`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=follow)" in questions gives 4,636 results and  majority of them have the words "follow up" in the title.  I think that makes it a good candidate for a tag so that unnecessary information can be extracted from the title, while still allowing users to search for these types of questions easily.

Comment: See Mat's Mugs deleted answer, and the comments to that answer here: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1200/31562

Comment: This tag is vastly different than game or programming-challenge. This is a meta-tag, those are not.

Answer (score 16):

## No.

Use a standard box instead:

```
A [previous version](link) of this code has been posted on Code Review before.
```

Comment: I agree.  I don't even see how [tag:follow-up] would provide a good grouping of questions, where [tag:game] questions are very related in what they do, [tag:follow-up] just says what they are.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't see how this tag is much different than [game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) or [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge), with this tag a user can follow the follow up posts like they would the game posts or the tic-tac-toe posts ([tic-tac-toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe))

But games and programming challenges *describe* the code itself.  The questions are also respectively similar in such a way.  *None* of the follow-up posts would have anything specific in common, which would go against good use of tags.  You seem to be thinking of this tag as more of a signpost and less of a means of organizing similar questions based on purpose.  This is why we put "follow-up" or something similar in the title.

Plus, if a follow-up question already has five very relevant tags, then there would be no room for a follow-up tag.  We don't need to hurt tag real-estate even further by factoring in such a tag.

Comment: now we are encroaching on [tag:beginner] which also doesn't describe the code itself, other than that a beginner wrote it.

Comment: @Malachi: Which is still something, though not quite content-oriented (and this isn't the place for yet another debate on that).